# Put a string from JSON into var

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, var

I'm a Linux sysadmin with very little coding experience. I was asked to develop a demo RCS chatbot in nodejs that would echo back any message it gets. I'm surprised I even got as far as I did, and I only have one last thing to do. I'm really enjoying this project and I was hoping I could ask for some help for the last piece. I'm trying to create a variable `OD` and put the value of `access_token`

I have this part of my code:

```
request5(options5, function (error, responseOD) {
              if (error) throw new Error(error);
              console.log(responseOD.body); // <--------------------------- Third line
              var OD = responseOD.body.access_token;
              console.log(OD); // <------------------------------- Fifth line
              var ODtoken = "Bearer ".concat(OD);
              });
```

The third line (I've written "third line" in the code snippet) returns this:

```
      {
        "token_type": "Bearer",
            "access_token": "cbYAmA9iElLteoAQrj9GsDT2VrnD",
            "expires_in": "7776000"
      }
```

but for some reason, the fifth line (`console.log(OD);`, I've written "fifth line" in the code snippet) returns:

```
undefined
```

Does anyone know why the `OD` variable won't receive the `access_token` from the JSON response?

Huge thanks ahead!

Comment: Try doing `console.log(typeof responseOD.body)` - if it's a string, you'll need to use `JSON.parse`

Comment: I just did `console.log(typeof responseOD.body)` and it returned string.

Do you happen to know how to use `JSON.parse` in this syntax to extract `access_token`?

Comment: Like this: `JSON.parse(responseOD.body).access_token`

Comment: YES! Thank you SO MUCH!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to parse that string body into a Javascript object using `JSON.parse(string)` function. In the end your code should look like this:

```js
request5(options5, function (error, responseOD) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    var bodyAsObject = JSON.parse(responseOD.body);
    var OD = bodyAsObject.access_token;
    var ODtoken = "Bearer ".concat(OD);
});
```